# How to create a new custom object in Salesforce and write a record to it?

Tags: python, salesforce

I am trying to create a new custom object in Salesforce with two fields. The object is being created, but I am not able to write any records to it.
Acc to the error, the fields are not present in the object.

```
import pandas as pd
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='user', password='pass', security_token='token')

name = "CustomObject13__c"
label = "CO13"

md_api = sf.mdapi
custom_object = md_api.CustomObject(
        fullName=name,
        label=label,
        pluralLabel="Custom Objects",
        nameField=md_api.CustomField(
                label="Name",
                type=md_api.FieldType("Text")
        ),
        fields=[{
                'fullName': 'Age__c',
                'label': 'Age',
                'type': 'Text',
                'length': 255
        },
                {
                        'fullName': 'Description__c',
                        'label': 'Description',
                        'type': 'TextArea'
                }],
        deploymentStatus=md_api.DeploymentStatus("Deployed"),
        sharingModel=md_api.SharingModel("Read")
)
md_api.CustomObject.create(custom_object)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Sal Vulcano', 'James Murray'], "Age__c": ["34", "54"],
                       "Description__c": ["tonight's big loser", "fool-proof plan"]})
for record in df.to_dict('records'):
    sf.__getattr__(name).create(record)
```

ERROR:

> simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://rawcubes-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/CustomObject13__c/. Response content: [{'message': "No such column 'Age__c' on sobject of type CustomObject13__c", 'errorCode': 'INVALID_FIELD'}]

[Object Manager - Fields and Relationships Viewer for the object 'CO13'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU3M8.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a sObject (table in database) - it's there but doesn't automatically mean you can see it. As sysadmin you bypass some checks when administering the org (making changes in Setup) - but API access will still stop you.

You need to grant the right to Create, Edit on the Object itself + Edit right on every custom field you added. You do that by editing your profile or permission sets (or creating new permission set and assigning it to your user by inserting new record into PermissionSetAssignment table).

So it's few more metadata operations for you before you can insert data. Typically it'd be done separately, first create table (even manually), then load...

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the help
Can I edit permissions for the newly created object through Python API itelf?

Comment: See if you can run update on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm, something like query then edit: `select id, field, PermissionsEdit from fieldpermissions where sobjecttype = 'CustomObject13__c' and Parent.Name = 'your permission set name goes here'`. If it doesn't work - you'd need another mdapi call similar to your object creation. Refer to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm, there's "fieldPermissions" in one of XMLs